# Way to Preview Twitter Widgets Locally

Tags: twitter, widget, local, preview

I'm building a website locally and would like to be able to see what the embedded Twitter widgets look like without uploading everything.

Here is the code for a basic Follow button ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pWpyb/)):

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/twitter" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="large" data-dnt="true">Follow @twitter</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

If you save this locally on your computer as whatever.html and then open it, you'll notice that the widget script never loads the widget.

Is there any way to get this to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `http:` before the word "platform" in this portion of the code:

```
src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"
```

so that it reads:

```
src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"
```